# Converting dates from the format "01-Jan-2017" into something usable in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have imported a data set into R, and the dates are in the format `01-Jan-2017`. I have tried using functions such as `as.Date()`, but it is not recognized as it is not in a standard format.

I wish to sort the columns by date, so I was hoping there was a way to convert the current format into something I can use in R.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lubridate::dmy("01-Jan-2017")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to the read the fine help page(s) telling you about the (required for `as.Date()` in your case) format string `%d-%b-%Y`, then the `anydate()` function of the [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) package is your friend:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anydate("01-Jan-2017")
[1] "2017-01-01"
R>
```

`anydate()` and the other functions in the package like `anytime()` *do not require a format* as they try common ones for you.

Answer (score 1):

The `as.Date()` method should work for this, but you need to specify the format.

```
date <- as.Date("01-Jan-2017", "%d-%b-%Y")
```

Comment: I am using R-3.3.3, windows 7.